# Upload file path from array to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, client-side, server-side

I currently am able to save multiple individual files to folder using an array. Now I would like to add the individual file paths from the folder into a database.

How would I be able to get the individual paths of each file uploaded to folder?

From there how would I insert those individual paths into my database into separate fields?

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```html
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
 
 $imageFileType = pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $path = 'uploads/' . $_FILES['my-file']['name'];
 
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}


$conn_info = "host=d port= dbname= user= password=";
        $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_info)
        or die('could not connect:' . pg_last_error());

         echo"<br/>sucessful connection";


        $query = "INSERT INTO photo2 (path) VALUES ('".$path."') ;";

        $result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
         if (!$result) {
         $errormessage = pg_last_error();
         echo "<br/> error with query: " . $errormessage;
         exit();
         }

         echo "<br/> file uploaded to PostgreSQL";

        pg_close();

?>
```

Comment: Add path and insert query in for loop.

Comment: sir i have a solution. you just need to change some code alignment. set the $conn_info variable first and then run the query inside the for loop

Comment: one more thing, you are not set the file extension to your path

Answer (score 0):

Get the path in for loop. And also write insert query in loop.
Database connection code has to be before for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "uploads/".$name_array[$i])){
        // get path
        $path = "uploads/".$name_array[$i];
        echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        // Insert query comes here
          $query = "INSERT INTO photo2 (path) VALUES ('".$path."') ;";
          pg_query($dbconn, $query);
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the full code you need. I think it's may help you sir.

```
<?php
$conn_info = "host=d port= dbname= user= password=";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_info) or die('could not connect:' . pg_last_error());

echo "<br/>sucessful connection";

if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

    // you don't need this lines of code
    // $imageFileType = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // $path = 'uploads/' . $_FILES['my-file']['name'] . '.' . $imageFileType;

    for($i=0;$i<count($tmp_name_array);$i++) {
        $path = "uploads/" . $name_array[$i];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], $path)){
            $query = "INSERT INTO photo2 (path) VALUES ('".$path."');";
            $result = pg_query($dbconn, $query);

            if (!$result) {
                $errormessage = pg_last_error();
                echo "<br/> error with query: " . $errormessage;

                exit();
            } else {
                echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}

echo "<br/> file uploaded to PostgreSQL";
pg_close();

?>
```